# How can I get the .img file from the path directory in python?

Tags: python

I have a file with the extension of **.img** ,in this path of my OS  `/home/amanda/workspace/FX36.img` . I dont know how can I access that file.img in python and use this file.img as a body in my code.

```
        js_body = dict()
        file_path ="/home/amanda/workspace/FX36.img"
        img=open(file_path ,"r")
        js_body["File"] = img
        js_res = self._post(rest_uri, js_body)
        return js_res
```

I dont know what should I put instead of

```
img=open(file_path ,"r")
```

till I have

```
js_body["File"] = FX36.img
```

I will be grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "body"?
Is your question about how to extract the filename from the full path? It should be a duplicate in that case.

Comment: what is `js_body` ? For what you want to use image ? To display in HTML in `<img>` ? Then send url for this image, no image .

Comment: I want to know how can I access to file.img  and then use it as in my dict().@Abitbol

Comment: I should write API that uploads this img.so I want to add this img to the js_body=dict() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img=open(file_path ,"r")
```

It only creates the stream. You need to call method `read()` to get actual content.

```
img = open(file_path, 'r').read()
```

If you want bytes use `rb` flag instead.

```
img_bytes = open(file_path, 'rb').read()
```

You also need to dispose the opened stream.

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    img = file.read()
```

I'd also advise against using raw paths in code. It'll crash on any OS, which uses different path conventions. Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead.

Comment: thanks for your response. I used your solution I got UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 10: invalid start byte ..... I also used rb and then encode('utf-8') but ...still I have errore